# Perl Regex Multiple Matches

Tags: regex, perl, backreference

I'm looking for a regular expression that will behave as follows:

> input: "hello world."
>
> output: he, el, ll, lo, wo, or, rl, ld

my idea was something along the lines of

```
    while($string =~ m/(([a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z]))/g) {
        print "$1-$2 ";
    }
```

But that does something a little bit different.

Comment: Nice question. I think I may have answered it before.  [Search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=code%3A%22%28*FAIL%29%22) for `(*FAIL)`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's tricky.  You have to capture it, save it, and then force a backtrack.

You can do that this way:

```
use v5.10;   # first release with backtracking control verbs

my $string = "hello, world!";
my @saved;

my $pat = qr{
    ( \pL {2} )
    (?{ push @saved, $^N })
    (*FAIL)
}x;

@saved = ();
$string =~ $pat;
my $count = @saved;
printf "Found %d matches: %s.\n", $count, join(", " => @saved);
```

produces this:

```
Found 8 matches: he, el, ll, lo, wo, or, rl, ld.
```

If you do not have v5.10, or you have a headache, you can use this:

```
my $string = "hello, world!";
my @pairs = $string =~ m{
  # we can only match at positions where the
  # following sneak-ahead assertion is true:
    (?=                 # zero-width look ahead
        (               # begin stealth capture
            \pL {2}     #       save off two letters
        )               # end stealth capture
    )
  # succeed after matching nothing, force reset
}xg;

my $count = @pairs;
printf "Found %d matches: %s.\n", $count, join(", " => @pairs);
```

That produces the same output as before.

But you might still have a headache.

Comment: Nice answer. Can you please explain the answer in brief?

Comment: @KrishnachandraSharma Hm, I thought I had. You capture it, save it in an external variable, then force a failure. The failure backtracks, the engine steps forward one because it made no progress, and we try again. Lather, rinse, repeat.

Comment: Great approach and answer, but this would a problem in older versions of Perl than 5.10.

Comment: Thanks, thought there would be a more straight forward way, but it gets the job done.

Comment: Always use `local our @var` instead of `my @var` for vars declared outside of `(?{ })` but used inside. Your code won't work inside a sub.

Comment: @KrishnachandraSharma Perl v5.10 came out in 2007. Do you know how many children have been born since then?

Comment: @tchrist Still, lower version are not obsolete right? I simply made my point!

Comment: @ikegami You're probably right, but I don't get any will-not-stay-shared type warnings. Care to explain? Is this related to the trick of using `local` *inside* the backtracking part so it pops things off? I don't want that to happen here.

Comment: `(?{ })` captures when the regex is compiled, which is at compile time. So that makes it like a named sub. There's really no problem until you move it into a sub, but when you do, you'll get `Variable "@saved" is not available`

Answer (score 5):

No need "to force backtracking"!

```
push @pairs, "$1$2" while /([a-zA-Z])(?=([a-zA-Z]))/g;
```

Though you might want to match any letter rather than the limited set you specified.

```
push @pairs, "$1$2" while /(\pL)(?=(\pL))/g;
```

Comment: Not as efficient, for starters.

Comment: That has the dreaded "`[A-Z]` code smell", you know. Good for avoiding jalapeños, bad for normal text.

Comment: @tchrist, The op never said anything about letters, but added a mention of `\pL`.

Comment: I always use `\pL` unless I'm working from an RFC that stipulates A-Z exclusively. I wish I remembered what the `(*FAIL)` is good for beyond the lookahead technique.

Comment: @tchrist, Used in conditionals too `(?(?{ condition() })(?!))`

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way to do it. Doesn't use any regexp magic, it does use nested `map`s but this could easily be translated to `for` loops if desired.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $in = "hello world.";
my @words = $in =~ /(\b\pL+\b)/g;

my @out = map {
  my @chars = split '';
  map { $chars[$_] . $chars[$_+1] } ( 0 .. $#chars - 1 );
} @words;

print join ',', @out;
print "\n";
```

Again, for me this is more readable than a strange regex, YMMV.

Comment: The more of these I read, the more I think ikegami's does what I attempt here with even more clarity.

Answer (score 0):

I would use captured `group` in lookahead..

```
(?=([a-zA-Z]{2}))
    ------------
         |->group 1 captures two English letters
```

try it [here](http://regexhero.net/tester/)

Comment: Works nicely.  Great answer.

Comment: What is an "alphabet"?  Greek is an alphabet. Latin is an alphabet. Cyrillic is an alphabet. That does not capture "alphabets"; that captures two upper- or lowercase letters between A and Z inclusive.  It fails on things like *façade*.

Comment: @tchrist op never mentioned that..a-zA-Z are still alphabets

Comment: @Some1.Kill.The.DJ Um, that is not what *alphabet* means in English. I suggest you check a dictionary.

Comment: @tchrist hope **English alphabets** makes it more clear to you :P

Comment: @Some1.Kill.The.DJ Aren't use listening? That is not what alphabet means. PLEASE see a dictionary.  The word *alphabet* is not a synonym for "an alphabetic character".

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by looking for letters and using the `pos` function to make use of the position of the capture, `\G` to reference it in another regex, and `substr` to read a few characters from the string.

```
use v5.10;
use strict;
use warnings;

my $letter_re = qr/[a-zA-Z]/;

my $string = "hello world.";
while( $string =~ m{ ($letter_re) }gx ) {
    # Skip it if the next character isn't a letter
    # \G will match where the last m//g left off.
    # It's pos() in a regex.
    next unless $string =~ /\G $letter_re /x;

    # pos() is still where the last m//g left off.
    # Use substr to print the character before it (the one we matched)
    # and the next one, which we know to be a letter.
    say substr $string, pos($string)-1, 2;
}
```

You can put the "check the next letter" logic inside the original regex with a zero-width positive assertion, `(?=pattern)`.  Zero-width meaning it is not captured and does not advance the position of a `m//g` regex.  This is a bit more compact, but zero-width assertions get can get tricky.

```
while( $string =~ m{ ($letter_re) (?=$letter_re) }gx ) {
    # pos() is still where the last m//g left off.
    # Use substr to print the character before it (the one we matched)
    # and the next one, which we know to be a letter.
    say substr $string, pos($string)-1, 2;
}
```

**UPDATE**: I'd originally tried to capture both the match and the look ahead as `m{ ($letter_re (?=$letter_re)) }gx` but that didn't work.  The look ahead is zero-width and slips out of the match.  Other's answers showed that if you put a second capture inside the look-ahead then it can collapse to just...

```
say "$1$2" while $string =~ m{ ($letter_re) (?=($letter_re)) }gx;
```

I leave all the answers here for TMTOWTDI, especially if you're not a regex master.

Comment: Do you really use `substr` and `pos`? Especially like this? I nearly never ever do. Part of it is because it is grapheme-hostile, but mostly it is because it's fiddly.

Comment: @tchrist In this case, it seemed the simplest way to do it.  `pos` and `substr` have the benefit of being straight forward to understand vs a regex with look-aheads and captures. I agree `pos` can change out from under you mysteriously, but small scopes forgive many sins.  My first impulse was a non-regex iterative solution, since "match every pair of letters" is pretty simple if you loop through characters. I tried to do it with a capture + look-ahead, but couldn't make it work; didn't realize you need to put a second capture inside the look-ahead, not around it.